# Aligning a rotated div under another div

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to align one rotated div under another div's bottom right edge. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I've got so far: https://codepen.io/jayceekay/pen/pGVBYL?editors=1100

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="heading">
    Some heading
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 3px dashed black;
  width: 200px;
}

.image {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I researched similar questions but all the solutions are bespoke and I wasn't able to find a truly dynamic solution that would work on any display. To achieve the example of what I want to achieve in the image above I added `margin-left: 100px;` to the `.heading` div but that hack breaks down in a lot of other situations/screen sizes.

Comment: Not sure if this helps because not a lot of information here, but you could place these divs inside of a table and simply apply the div to the 2nd column of the 2nd row?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd separate the content from the presentation for simplicity. Needs a little tweaking to work out the whitespace around the blue box.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 3px dashed black;
  width: 200px;
}

.image-box {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-box"></div>
  
  <div class="heading-box">
    <div class="heading">
      Some heading
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep the DOM structure the below works.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 3px dashed black;
  width: 200px;
}

.image {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="heading">
    Some heading
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is define where the rotation anchors to by using `transform-origin`:

```
.heading {
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeaLgz?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of clever solution. I removed flexbox b/c it's not necessary - but I'm sure you can add it back if you are one of those that doesn't like floats. You have to rotate the wrapping `.heading-box` 180deg. Then you can rotate the heading -90deg from its top left origin:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOYPNz?editors=1100

```
.container::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.image {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading-box {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.heading {
  float: left;
  background-color: skyblue;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: 100px;
}
```